# Resizable não funciona em imagem dinâmica

Tags: jquery, upload, jquery-ui

Tenho uma ferramenta que quando o usuário envia qualquer imagem a função `resizable` não funciona, ao contrário da imagem estática que já está no site.

Projetei online a minha dúvida, no seguinte link:
http://www.rafaelseverino.com/nav/resizable

Se tiverem uma alternativa usando `jQuery`, seria uma boa.

```
function doClick() {
  var el = document.getElementById("fileElem");
  if (el) {
    el.click();
  }
}

function handleFiles(files) {
    // onchange do formulário
    var d = document.getElementById("draggable");       
    var list = document.createElement("ul");        
    d.appendChild(list);
    for (var i=0; i < files.length; i++) {
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        list.appendChild(li);                       
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.width = 100;
        img.classList.add("ui-widget-content");
        img.classList.add("resizable");
        img.classList.add("ui-resizable");  
        img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(files[i]);
        img.onload = function() {
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(this.src);
        }
        li.appendChild(img);
    }
}
$(function() {
  // Redimensionameto que só está funcionando na imagem estática
    $( ".resizable" ).resizable({
        maxHeight: 194,
        maxWidth: 150,
        minHeight: 95,
        minWidth: 70
    });
});
```

Comment: Rafael, bemvindo. Você tem imensos scripts a carregar na sua página, difícil ver tudo e ter a certeza do problema. Dá para fazer um exemplo simplificado do seu problema no jsFiddle por exemplo?

Comment: Obrigado Sérgio, o .resizable() só funciona com a imagem estática do site, acho que quando uma nove imagem é criada no DOM ele não funciona.

Comment: A parte do $( ".resizable" ).resizable() tem que ficar dentro da função handleFiles(files) Logo após a linha li.appendChild(img); sua informação ajudou muito, obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente executar o .resizable() depois de carregar a imagem.

Comment: Era isso mesmo Luís, depois do código onde a imagem é enviada pelo usuário, eu adicionei o código $( ".resizable" ).resizable(); Logo o redimensionamento só funciona quando a imagem é criada, antes disso não.